# How do I run capistrano with rinari in a system with rvm?

Tags: ruby, emacs, capistrano, rvm, rinari

This happens when I try to run rinari-cap:

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)

Something similar happens in eshell

I already installed the rvm.el file with no luck either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the rvm gem to the gemfile, and on the first line of deploy.rb:

```
ENV['rvm_path']||="~/.rvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line at the top of deploy.rb solved my issue:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
```